# Extract tables from text using regular expression

Tags: python, pandas, regex, nlp

I want to extract table from the example text as follows but my out put is not correct. My sample text, code, current output and expected output is as follows. any help is appreciated.

> dic = {'ID': ':  ID\nRespondent ID\nBased upon 3,302 valid cases out
> of 3,302 total cases.\n•Mean: 54361.66\n•Minimum: 10005.00\n•Maximum:
> 99992.00\n•Standard Deviation: 25723.74\nLocation: 1-5 (width: 5; decimal: 0)\nVariable Type:  numeric \n',  'VIS': ':  visit\nSwan
> study visit number\nValue Label Unweighted\nFrequency%\n00- 3302 100.0
> %\n Total 3,302 100%\nBased upon 3,302 valid cases out of 3,302 total
> cases.\nLocation: 6-7 (width: 2; decimal: 0)\nVariable Type:
> character \n',  'INT': ':  day\nDate form completed\nValue Label
> Unweighted\nFrequency%\n0- 3302 100.0 %\n Total 3,302 100%\nBased upon
> 3,302 valid cases out of 3,302 total cases.\n•Mean: 0.00\n•Median:
> 0.00\n•Mode: 0.00\n•Minimum: 0.00\n•Maximum: 0.00\n•Standard Deviation: 0.00\nLocation: 8-8 (width: 1; decimal: 0)\nVariable Type:
> numeric \n',  'AG0': ': Age in months\n- 2 -Value Label
> Unweighted\nFrequency%\n42- 367 11.1 %\n43- 421 12.7 %\n44- 416 12.6
> %\n45- 389 11.8 %\n46- 400 12.1 %\n47- 392 11.9 %\n48- 299 9.1 %\n49-
> 255 7.7 %\n50- 168 5.1 %\n51- 115 3.5 %\n52- 71 2.2 %\n53- 40.1 %\n
> Missing Data   \n.- 50.2 %\n Total 3,302 100%\nBased upon 3,297 valid
> cases out of 3,302 total cases.\n•Mean: 45.85\n•Median: 46.00\n•Mode:
> 43.00\n•Minimum: 42.00\n•Maximum: 53.00\n•Standard Deviation: 2.69\nLocation: 9-10 (width: 2; decimal: 0)\nVariable Type:  numeric \n',  'PRE0': ': Currently preant?\nAre you currently pnant?\nValue
> Label Unweighted\nFrequency%\n1No 3295 99.8 %\n2Yes 00.0 %\n Missing
> Data   \n-9Missing 70.2 %\n Total 3,302 100%\nBased upon 3,295 valid
> cases out of 3,302 total cases.\n•Minimum: 1.00\n•Maximum:
> 1.00\nLocation: 11-12 (width: 2; decimal: 0)\nVariable Type:  numeric \n- 3 -(Range of) Missing Values:  -9 , -8 , -7 , -1\n',}

```
import re
import pandas as pd

data = {}
for key, value in dic.items():
    regex = r'(Value\s+Label\s+Unweighted\s+Frequency%\s+(?:Missing\s+Data\s+)?[\s\S]+?)\n(?=\S)'
    match = re.search(regex, value, flags=re.DOTALL)
    if match:
        rows = [re.split(r"\s+", row.strip()) for row in match.group(1).strip().split("\n")]
        df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=["Value", "Label", "Unweighted"," Frequency%"])
        df["Variable"] = key
        data[key] = df

data["VISIT"]
```

the current output:

```
    Value       Label   Unweighted  Frequency%  Variable
0   Value       Label   Unweighted  None        VISIT
1   Frequency%  None    None        None        VISIT
2   00-         3302    100.0       %           VISIT
3   Total      3,302    100%        None        VISIT
```

Expected output:
This is only an example for few keys. I need this for all keys of dictionary

```
dic = {id:"no_table",VIS:Value  Label  Unweighted       Frequency%
                         00     -            3302            100.0 %
                                Total        3,302           100%
                     ,INT:Value Label  Unweighted       Frequency%
                         00     -            3302            100.0 %
                                Total        3,302           100% 
                      ,}
```

Update :

```
import re
import pandas as pd

# Define the regular expression pattern to match the table rows
pattern = r'(?P<Value>[\w.-]+)\s+(?P<Label>.+?)\s+(?P<Unweighted_Frequency>.+%)'


# Initialize an empty list to store the rows
rows = []

# Loop through the dictionary
for key, text in dic.items():
    # Find all the matches of the pattern in the text
    matches = re.findall(pattern, text)
    if matches:
        # Add the matches to the rows list with the key as the first column
        rows.extend([(key,) + match for match in matches])

# Create a pandas DataFrame from the rows list with the desired column names
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['Variable', 'Value', 'Label', 'Unweighted Frequency%'])
```

current out put is close but I dont know how to fix it :
1- what is under Unweighted Frequency% should be under only %
2- what is under Label should be under Unweighted Frequency
3 - what is under value is correct except for when the value is 1No , 1 should be under value and No should be under Label.
4- the last row is missing

This is not the full output only a sample.
Variable  Value   Label   Unweighted Frequency%

```
7           AG0     42-     367      11.1 %
8           AG0     43-     421      12.7 %
9           AG0     44-     416      12.6 %
10          AG0     45-     389      11.8 %
18          AG0 Missing Data    .-   50.2 %
19          AG0     Total   3,302    100%
20          PRE0    Value   Label   Unweighted  Frequency%
21          PRE0    1No     3295     99.8 %
22          PRE0    Missing Data    -9Missing 70.2 %
23          PRE0    Total   3,302    100%'''
```

Comment: Is the PDF you're working with publically available? It may help to see the source data if possible.

Comment: No and I am really stucked..

Comment: Text is not enough?

Comment: Text may be enough, I will have a closer look. It's usually possible to get better results extracting data like this as a table. pdfplumber's table detection settings are all customizable if the defaults don't extract the data cleanly: https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber#extracting-tables

Comment: In its current form there are parts that are really hard to extract, e.g. _"... Value Label Unweighted\nFrequency%\n1No 3295 99.8 %\n2Yes 00.0 %\n Missing Data \n-9Missing **70.2** %\n Total 3,302 100% ..."_: in the bold part the `Unweighted` is `7` and the `Frequency%` is `0.2%`. To disentagle those parts correctly you have to make decisions based on the actual values, and not only the form. I don't see a reasonable way to do that **all** by code.